# Android Emulator for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android-emulator

I installed a JDK and then an Android SDK on my Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit machine (2 GB DDR3 memory). The aim is to have an Android emulator. I created some Android Virtual Devices, one of which I named 'Andreud'. When I type in the command

```
emulator @Andreud
```

where 'Andreud' is the name of the Android Virtual Device I created. A blank window with a black backdrop shows up on which "android" word is visible, in its trademark font. This, I suppose, is the welcome screen. The home screen, icons, etc. don't show up. Also, there are buttons for volume control and also the power on button, all of which are enabled. Even the D-pad buttons which has 4 navigation buttons left, right, top, bottom, and a central button are enabled. There are other important buttons, home button, menu button which are disabled. It just shows a welcome screen and for minutes on end and goes blank again.

I would like (barest minimum) one of my Android Virtual Devices to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Though not solving your problem with SDK's emulator, you might want to take a look at [Jar of Beans](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/jar-of-beans-a-portable-android-emulator/), which is an alternative emulator created by an XDA member. Written in Java, it is platform independent, and thus should run on Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What system are you running the emulator on? At the moment, it just seems like your system is probably too slow to run the emulator. The emulator is very resource intensive, and unless you have a high end machine it's going to be very slow.

For the start, you'd want to start with a smaller screen resolution. Tablet-sized screen resolution is practically impossible to emulate unless you have a very high-end machine, try WQVGA size. Next check how much RAM you allocate for the virtual machine, if it exceeds the amount of free RAM you usually have when you don't have the emulator running, then it's going to be very slow due to heavy swapping. Also, close other applications running on the system to free up resources.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works in WQVGA size and I installed Whatsapp in it. The only thing that remains is to verify my phone number :-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you run on slow machine, but if you setting it properly, would be running better...

For example you had configured [KVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)?

Then when you run emulator, add these string at the end:

```
-qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
```

You had download a x86 or x86_64 image (it can run natively and more faster)?

What kind of system_image you would run?